# How to save an ID from a table to another table in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

I have a problem regarding passing 'slot_id' (auto-incremented primary key) from `tb_parkingslots` to `tb_freeslot` and save it.

Here's my code:

Controller:

```
// GET: Admin/Create
public ActionResult Addspace()
{
    return View();
}

// POST: Admin/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Addspace(FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        tb_parkingslots add = new tb_parkingslots();
        add.slot_name = collection["name"];

        db.tb_parkingslots.Add(add);
        int i = db.SaveChanges();

        if (i > 0)
        {
           tb_freeslot addi = new tb_freeslot();
           addi.slot_id = Convert.ToInt32(collection["id"]); //which is auto increment - primary key in tb_parkingslots
           addi.slot_name = collection["name"];

           db.tb_freeslot.Add(addi);
           db.SaveChanges();

           ViewBag.s = "success";
           return View();
       }
       else
       {
           ViewBag.f = "failed";
           return View();
       }
   }
   catch
   {
       return View();
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem or error you are getting?

Comment: @abhinavpratap when add a 'slot_name' in 'tb_parkingslots', 'slot_id' get incremented by one. At the same i want to save 'slot_id' and 'slot_name' in 'tb_freeeslot'. problem is that 'slot_id' can't save in 'tb_freeslot'.there is no issue in saving 'slot_name'

Comment: `tb_parkingslots` once you done `Save changes` class `id` automatic set please debug your code

Comment: Try using this line `addi.slot_id = add["slot_id"]` instead of the line you currently have. Also, I would urge you to use **more descriptive** and more intuitive variable names - `add` for a variable of type `tb_parkingslot` is both dangerous (because `add` is an often used expression), and not very informative - use something like `parkingSlot` that really expresses what it is you're dealing with

Comment: @marc_s how is it possible that indexing with [ ] to an expression of type tb_parkingslots

Comment: Sorry - my mistake - should have been `addi.slot_id = add.slot_id;` - or whatever the `id` column in your `tb_parkingslots` object is called. The point is: once you've saved the `tb_parkingslots` object using EF, its properties (including the `slot_id` property with the auto-incremented PK value) will be **set** and you can just read out that property value.

Comment: @marc_s yes, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you save data in tb_parkingslots table. EF will automatically fill the Id property of the object.

```
 tb_parkingslots add = new tb_parkingslots();
        add.slot_name = collection["name"];

        db.tb_parkingslots.Add(add);
        int i = db.SaveChanges(); // Here you will get the ID.
```

You can then use this ID for saving data in tb_freeslot table.

```
tb_freeslot addi = new tb_freeslot();
           addi.slot_id = add.id; //which is slot ID when you saved data in tb_parkingslots
           addi.slot_name = collection["name"];

           db.tb_freeslot.Add(addi);
           db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: value is passed, when i debug. but which isn't show in db table. ie, in tb_freeslot

Comment: yes it works. have an issue with tables and solved it